# REST http status code for content that needs authentication?

Tags: http, rest

I have a web application that uses RESTful url patterns. Currently if a users tries to access a page where they need to be authenticated it just returns nothing. Is it good practice to return the HTTP status code in this case? Would I use 403 or a different one?

Comment: REST has nothing to do with URI patterns. "RESTful url patterns" is utter nonsense. I suspect your API is simply RPC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should send a response with the HTTP status code.

I wouldn't send a **403 Forbidden** back though as the spec specifies for this status code :

> The server understood the request, but
>   is refusing to fulfill it.
>   Authorization will not help and the
>   request SHOULD NOT be repeated

Return a **401 Unauthorized** status code instead.  See this for more info on the status codes:

http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html

The way I do this with Jersey is to send a response with the status and then include a String entity which contains a human readable message, e.g.

```
Response response = Response.status(Status.PRECONDITION_FAILED).entity(
                    new String("Incorrect " + id + " [" + id + "]")).build();
```

This will be displayed to the client.  I throw a Jersey WebApplicationException which wraps this response.

Comment: Thanks Jon, this was most helpful.

Answer (score 1):

If they don't have permissions return 401 to give them the chance to respond to the authentication challenge or 403 if you don't want them to.

[Restlet 1.1](http://www.restlet.org/) onwards return 403, while earlier versions return 401. 403 seems to be regarded as more correct, if not necessarily more helpful.

Answer (score 0):

It depends.  You really ought to return something, of course, just to have a decent client experience.  If you'd like to give them opportunity to authenticate at that moment, you can return a 401 and the client will know to pass credentials using standard authentication.  If, however, you'd prefer that they authenticate through some other mechanism (some login URL and then set a cookie or somesuch), then returning a 403 is probably the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

lol... in the REST API implementation I just built I returned a 401 status code with a response body that read "goodbye".  Was the first thing complained about by guy interacting with API.  I still think "goodbye" said it all  ; )